# Imported existing Android project error on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dependencies, apk-expansion-files

I've got many errors on my project recently which I'd imported on eclipse. 
The project build target is Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10) and minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion
is "9" and "14" respectively. In addition, Zip_file, library(licensing), and (Google Play) downloader_library have been added to the project.

The point is I have no idea with the errors appeared.

Window -> Show Views -> Problems -> 4errors (4items)

```
Project 'downloader_library' is missing required library :'/Users/Documents/Folder/downloader_library/bin/downloader_library.jar'
The Container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library'/Users/Documents/Folder/downloader_library/bin/downloader_library.jar'
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

You know what I've put the 'downloader_library.jar' as the same path above but errors are still exist.

Errors extra :

com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl/downloader_library/V14CustomNotification

```
Notification.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
Multiple markers at this line - Notification.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
                          - Notification.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
```

project/package/

```
The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent
ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH cannot be resolved or is not a field
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE cannot be resolved or is not a field
The hierarchy of the type MarketActivity is inconsistent
The import android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback cannot be resolved
The import android.nfc.NfcEvent cannot be resolved
The import com.google.android.vending.expansion cannot be resolved
The import com.google.android.vending.expansion cannot be resolved
CreateNdefMessageCallback cannot be resolved to a type
The method setNdefPushMessageCallback(MuseumActivity, MuseumActivity) is undefined for the type NfcAdapter
Helpers cannot be resolved
DownloaderClientMarshaller cannot be resolved
NfcEvent cannot be resolved to a type
DownloaderService cannot be resolved to a type
The method getPublicKey() of type ExpansionFileDownloaderService must override or implement a supertype method
The method getSALT() of type ExpansionFileDownloaderService must override or implement a supertype method
The method getAlarmReceiverClassName() of type ExpansionFileDownloaderService must override or implement a supertype method
```

All I want to do is just editing some codes in application but i can't even build this project. I've wasted 7days for this. What should I do. Please give me a help.

Comment: have  you checked in project property>java build path that your library has been added...or not

Comment: right click on your project--> properties--> build path--> libraries --> dependencies. Check which one ahs error and try fixing it. Or show us a snapshot

Comment: make sure you import all the necessary JARs. fix the properties if it requires any imported project as well. try to clean and rebuild.

Comment: is your downloader_library a jar file? Where it actually resides?

Comment: You may have copy the project into workspace directory. and then imported it. please avoid this, it always cause problems, like above.

Comment: @arjun.9990 yes i did. oh i wasted the time because of the copied project... thanks a lot.

Comment: welcome @user3503072, can i put my comment as answer?

Comment: @JijuInduchoodan yes, the jar file is in the downloader_library/bin/ but sometimes it disapeared when i clean the project.

Comment: place the necessary jar files inside the libs folder and do Add to Build path option for all of the added jar files inside that.

Comment: @arjun.9990 i didn't copy the project this time but i get 255 errors now. Do you have any idea with an error on downloader_library/res/value-v9?

Comment: @user3503072 make sure target=android-?? matches android-sdk you already have in project.properties file. then try to clean project.

Comment: @arjun.9990 oh i forgot! I changed the target same as the project but still have same errors such as Android Dependencies error and NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD,HSPAP,LTE cannot be resolved or is not a filed, Notification.Builder cannot be resolved to a type, TYPE_BLUETOOTH,ETHERNET cannot be resolved or is not a filed errors.

Comment: @arjun.9990 Do you think the downloader_library cause those sort of problems? :-(

Comment: @user3503072 i now nothing about the downloader_library. And i think you are making some mistake in building. i can help if you provide the project.

Comment: @arjun.9990 I really appreciate your help but i can't send it because of my company's rules. I feel disaster...omg I think i have a look for my mistake in building. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

download latest android sdk from here, http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

open the sdk manager and install the libraries required for the project. make a new project. copy all the layout files in this new project, and then clean the project. now make new java files with same names and copy the code. create entries in manifest files. it should work now.
same problem existed for me. adding the libraries in java build path didn't work.